# What's the purpose of adding the extra 'views:{'foo':{}}' when declaring a view in angular?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, view, angular-ui-router

What's the purpose of declaring the a view with `views:{}` e.g.

```
.state('app.example', {
    url: "/example",
    views: {
      'my-example': {
        templateUrl: "views/example.html",
        controller: 'myCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

as opposed to this

```
 .state('app.example', {
        url: "/example"
        templateUrl: "views/example.html",
        controller: 'myCtrl'
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out and I created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/garrettmac/pen/YwKwqK/) for this to get it to fit nicely inside other ionic app. This updates the child view when a button or a sidemenu item is pressed with more detail inside the codepen by making **multiple** child views share a name like so

```
     views: {
            'shared-child-view' :{
              templateUrl: "[path to your children, in our case child1.html and child2.html]"
            }
          }`
```

where it would look something like this

```
 .state('sidemenu.parent.child1', {
      url: "/child1",
      views: {
        'shared-child-view' :{
          templateUrl: "child1.html"
        }
      }
    })
       .state('sidemenu.parent.child2', {
      url: "/child2",
      views: {
   'shared-child-view': {
     templateUrl: "child2.html"
   }
 }
    })
`
```

Where it can sit in a parent that sits in an abstract state like this (but it doesnt have to but It's likely that this is how your ionic app will be setup):

```
.state('sidemenu', {
  url: "/sidemenu",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "sidemenu.html"
})
.state('sidemenu.parent', {
  url: "/parent",
  views: {
    'menuContent' :{
      templateUrl: "parent.html"
    }
  }
})
```

You can **alternate or change each child view** inside a view to evrey view with the same name, in this case "**shared-child-state**"

```
  <div ui-view name="shared-child-view"></div>
```

and it can be made **clickable** with

```
<a href="#/sidemenu/parent/child2" class="item">Child View 2
              </a>
```

This doesnt work if you use `ui-serf`.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

It is used for having **multiple parallel views** for a single state. Example:

```
.state('app.example', {
    url: "/example",
    views: {
        "example1": {
            template: 'app.example.view1'
        },
        "example2": {
            template: 'app.example.view2'
        }
    }
})
```

index.html

```
<ui-view = "view1">
</ui-view>

<ui-view = "view2">
</ui-view>
```

So effectively, your state has two parallel views. You can find the detailed explanation [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

Comment: Ok that makes since why they get used in tabs and sideview/sidemenus. How would this work (whats best practice) when dealing with child states of multiple parallel views?

Comment: Sorry, never used nested states for parallel views. Maybe frame this as a separate question?

Answer (score 0):

It is used to show multiple views on a single page(state).We use the above method when we show multiple parallel views on a single page.Suppose you have a page in which you have to show different charts on different positions,we created multiple views and appended the chart on those positions.Hope this helps